# how to save an imshow picture in an matrix in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, edit

i have generated an image by imshow( I, [100 200]);
now i want this displayed image to be stored in another matrix which is to be used later for ssim function.
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function for that - [`getimage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getimage.html). If you have more than one image in a particular axes - see also [`imhandles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhandles.html).

Alternatively, if you have a handle to the image (i.e. if you previously did `hIm = imshow( I, [100 200]);`) you can simply use `imMat = get(hIm,'CData');`.

Comment: in which variable will the resultant image be saved??

Comment: In the variable you assign it to.... In the case of `A = getimage(h)` the variable is called `A`. In the case of `imMat = get(hIm,'CData');` - `imMat`.

Comment: but i keep on getting the original image..withot the paramter [100 200] affecing the result

Comment: If you only want to keep the data that is between 100 and 200, just do `I1=I; I1(I1>200 | I1<100)=NaN;`